# Spark's toDS vs to DF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I understand that one can convert an RDD to a Dataset using `rdd.toDS`. However there also exists `rdd.toDF`.  Is there really any benefit of one over the other?

After playing with the Dataset API for a day, I find out that almost any operation takes me out to a DataFrame (for instance `withColumn`). After converting an RDD with `toDS`, I often find out that another conversion to a DataSet is needed, because something brought me to a DataFrame again.

Am I using the API wrongly? Should I stick with .toDF and only convert to a DataSet in the end of a chain of operations? Or is there a benefit to using toDS earlier?

Here is a small concrete example

```
spark
  .read
  .schema (...)
  .json (...)
  .rdd
  .zipWithUniqueId
  .map[(Integer,String,Double)] { case (row,id) => ... }
  .toDS // now with a Dataset API (should use toDF here?)
  .withColumnRenamed ("_1", "id" ) // now back to a DataFrame, not type safe :(
  .withColumnRenamed ("_2", "text")
  .withColumnRenamed ("_2", "overall")
  .as[ParsedReview] // back to a Dataset
```

Comment: DataFrame is just an alias for ```Dataset<Row>``` - Databricks has some content regarding Dataset/DataFrame's: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/index.html

Also agildata has a quick primer on the syntax here: http://www.agildata.com/apache-spark-rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-dataset/

I recommend avoiding converting between the two as much as possible. If you're content with DataFrame's, use them, but if you can swing it, Dataset can often be more optimal. In fact, it's fine to use the type Dataset<Row> in place of DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the pointers.  I realize that this is just an alias.  I hate the untyped nature of the Dataframe api. Most of the errors are reported at runtime, and this is a real pain for someone who is only learning the framework.  Are there some guidelines on how to stay in the polymorphic Dataset? (so that I don't have to loose and restore types like in the above examples?)

Comment: You should be able to create a ```Dataset<ParsedReview>``` with only some of the values specified, then modify those values via a ```map``` call over the objects using setters. The example you gave is not as clear to me as it probably is to you. Using the convenience methods like withColumnRenamed means sacrificing the type safety of Datasets for the simplicity of dynamic column renaming. One thing worth considering is using the ```row.getString(row.fieldIndex("column_name"))``` syntax which would afford you relative type safety with the Dataset<Row>/DataFrame values.

Comment: @Garren, yes. I could indeed move toDS before the map.  This would give a slightly longer computation in the type safe world.  However, I am suprised by the difficulty to rename columns.  The types are not changing with renaming. So this should be safe, but I found no respective API.

Answer (score 6):

Michael Armburst nicely explained that shift to dataset and dataframe and the difference between the two. Basically in spark 2.x they converged dataset and dataframe API into one with slight difference. 
"DataFrame is just DataSet of generic row objects. When you don't know all the fields, DF is the answer".
[image: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1a4pgYzeFwE]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question (I should have made it more clear) is more of a dissatisfaction with the Dataset API. I seem to be unable to do a lot of stuff wtihout dropping down to DataFrames which are not type safe (occasionally I also need to drop to RDDs but this is fine, as these are type safe).